Disable broken (white) pixels of damaged screen
My Google Pixel 5 screen has a bright white vertical column of pixels covering the left 2-3 mm of the screen. As a dark mode user, it's very bright! I don't have the money to replace the phone or screen right now.
Is there a way, in software/config, to somehow disable the white light from the vertical line? Perhaps telling Android that the screen is narrower than it is, and center or right justify the content? Or just telling Android to just turn off the left 2-3 mm of pixels and loose the content under them?

Have you tried a factory reset and/or powering off the phone for some minutes? Such problems are usually a hardware defect which means the screen ignores the pixel color sent by the OS and displays a different color (in your case white). I don't see a way to have any impact on this problem using software or configuration changes. A hardware problem can only be fixed on hardware level.

@Robert, that looks like an answer to me, so why is it in the comments?  :-)
